# Rearranging variables using dplyr's select and everything()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to rearrange variables in a data frame using `dplyr's` `select` and `everything()`.

Create a data frame.

```
> library(dplyr)
> X <- tibble(a = seq(0, 10),
              b = seq(10, 20),
              c = seq(20, 30),
              d = seq(30, 40),
              e = seq(40, 50))
```

I can move `c` to the front of list.

```
> X %>% select(c, everything())
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       c     a     b     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    20     0    10    30    40
 2    21     1    11    31    41
 3    22     2    12    32    42
 4    23     3    13    33    43
 5    24     4    14    34    44
 6    25     5    15    35    45
 7    26     6    16    36    46
 8    27     7    17    37    47
 9    28     8    18    38    48
10    29     9    19    39    49
11    30    10    20    40    50
```

But if I want to move `c` to end of the list, this does not work.

```
> X %>% select(everything(), c)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       a     b     c     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     0    10    20    30    40
 2     1    11    21    31    41
 3     2    12    22    32    42
 4     3    13    23    33    43
 5     4    14    24    34    44
 6     5    15    25    35    45
 7     6    16    26    36    46
 8     7    17    27    37    47
 9     8    18    28    38    48
10     9    19    29    39    49
11    10    20    30    40    50
```

However, the following accomplishes moving `c` to end.

```
> X %>% select(-c, everything(), c)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       a     b     d     e     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     0    10    30    40    20
 2     1    11    31    41    21
 3     2    12    32    42    22
 4     3    13    33    43    23
 5     4    14    34    44    24
 6     5    15    35    45    25
 7     6    16    36    46    26
 8     7    17    37    47    27
 9     8    18    38    48    28
10     9    19    39    49    29
11    10    20    40    50    30
```

But can we do both? I.e. can we move something to the front, something to end. For example, can I move `b` to the front and `c` to the end?

This does not work. The `c` needs to move to the end.

```
> X %>% select(b, -c, everything(), c)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       b     a     c     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    10     0    20    30    40
 2    11     1    21    31    41
 3    12     2    22    32    42
 4    13     3    23    33    43
 5    14     4    24    34    44
 6    15     5    25    35    45
 7    16     6    26    36    46
 8    17     7    27    37    47
 9    18     8    28    38    48
10    19     9    29    39    49
11    20    10    30    40    50
```

This does not work. The `b` does not move to the start.

```
> X %>% select(-c, b, everything(), c)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       a     b     d     e     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     0    10    30    40    20
 2     1    11    31    41    21
 3     2    12    32    42    22
 4     3    13    33    43    23
 5     4    14    34    44    24
 6     5    15    35    45    25
 7     6    16    36    46    26
 8     7    17    37    47    27
 9     8    18    38    48    28
10     9    19    39    49    29
11    10    20    40    50    30
```

So my question: Using `select` and `everything()`, can I move some variables to the start of the list and some to the end, with everything else in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This moves `c` to the end:

```
select(X, -c, c)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       a     b     d     e     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     0    10    30    40    20
 2     1    11    31    41    21
 3     2    12    32    42    22
 4     3    13    33    43    23
 5     4    14    34    44    24
 6     5    15    35    45    25
 7     6    16    36    46    26
 8     7    17    37    47    27
 9     8    18    38    48    28
10     9    19    39    49    29
11    10    20    40    50    30
```

This moves b to the front and c to the end:

```
select(X, b, everything(), -c, c)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       b     a     d     e     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    10     0    30    40    20
 2    11     1    31    41    21
 3    12     2    32    42    22
 4    13     3    33    43    23
 5    14     4    34    44    24
 6    15     5    35    45    25
 7    16     6    36    46    26
 8    17     7    37    47    27
 9    18     8    38    48    28
10    19     9    39    49    29
11    20    10    40    50    30
```

Comment: Gabor, OP wants `b` as the first column and `c` as the last one, with the rest in between.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. Basically, you select `b` and `c` as the first and last column. The rest of the column names is obtained with: `names(X)[!names(X) %in% c("b","c")]`

```
X %>% select(b, names(X)[!names(X) %in% c("b","c")], c)
# A tibble: 11 x 5
       b     a     d     e     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    10     0    30    40    20
 2    11     1    31    41    21
 3    12     2    32    42    22
 4    13     3    33    43    23
 5    14     4    34    44    24
 6    15     5    35    45    25
 7    16     6    36    46    26
 8    17     7    37    47    27
 9    18     8    38    48    28
10    19     9    39    49    29
11    20    10    40    50    30
```